# How to remove strange selection on contentEditable after document.execCommand('justifyRight')?

Tags: javascript, html, execcommand

### Problem

Strange static or blinking selection after execution of command

```
document.execCommand('justifyRight', false, null)
```

and ***re-selecting*** of contentEditable content or some portions of it.

[image]

### To reproduce

1. Create contentEditable element with text
2. Execute `document.execCommand('justifyRight', false, null)` on it
3. Try to select some text fragment on contentEditable a couple of times to see the artifact on the right side of contentEditable

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function onAlignRight() {
 document.execCommand('justifyRight', false, null);
}
```

```css
#input {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#button {
  user-select: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="input" contentEditable="true">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="button">
Align right
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Range and Selection

That strange blinking line looks like a **[range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/Range)**. The following demo uses the **[Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)** and **[Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)** API as well as the **[`.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)** method.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**
**Note:** Within the `#input` I added `<div>`s. The purpose of that is to represent content that was entered by a user, which are wrapped in `<div>`s. Text in `#input` wouldn't normally be a direct child node.

```js
let l = document.getElementById('left');
let r = document.getElementById('right');
let input = document.getElementById('input');

r.onclick = function(e) {
  // If not initially focused on input, it will fail
  input.focus();
  document.execCommand('justifyRight', false, null);
  /* Determines and sets caret position and narrows
  selection down to caret position*/
  setCaret();
}

l.onclick = function(e) {
  input.focus();
  document.execCommand('justifyLeft', false, null);
  setCaret();
}

function setCaret() {
  // Get selected area
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  // Get the number of chars on line caret is on
  let col = sel.focusOffset;
  // Get index number of div caret is on
  let row = sel.focusNode;
  // Make a range object representing the selection of text
  let rng = document.createRange();
  // Set the div range is on
  rng.selectNode(row);
  // Set the char position
  rng.setStart(row, col);
  // Set the range to the length of 1
  rng.collapse(true);
  // Clear any and all ranges
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  // Add the new range 
  sel.addRange(rng);
}
```

```css
#input {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

button {
  user-select: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="input" contentEditable="true">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
    remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
  <div>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</section>
<button id="left">
  Align left
</button>
<button id="right">
  Align right
</button>
```

Comment: This solution reduces chances to see the problem, but it still happens. Just align some portion of text to the right and play around selecting different areas from the right side.

Comment: What browser are you using and are you using PC or Mac?

Comment: PC, Chrome 69.0.3497.100

Comment: I've tested on PC Chrome, Firefox, and Edge latest versions and cannot reproduce the behavior...

Comment: I've checked Edge - no problem. But Opera and Chrome both have it.